# How to show error message if the pdf file is already open?

Tags: c#, pdf

when I try to open my pdf report from my program, if the pdf file is already open it shows exception like  ***"The process cannot access the file 'path..\sample.pdf' because it is being used by another process".***. how can I show a message that the document is open. or how can I reopen the same opened pdf file according to my request?? It shows exception on this line

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"F:\\reports\\" + "DepartmentPresentReport.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Go through this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: If you add @ character in front of a string  backslash is not a escape charcter   @"F:\reports\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first simple solution is that you can use `try catch` statement to open the file and handle the error based on the `error message (ID)`

Comment: how to find ***error message (ID)*** I am getting only exception

Comment: I did like this  " int code = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionCode() " it works..

Answer (score 1):

try using a try/catch to handle the exception

```
try
{
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"F:\\reports\\" + "DepartmentPresentReport.pdf", FileMode.Create));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // close already open file/ return exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even catch the exception using FileStream

```
private bool IsFileInUse(string path, FileAccess access = FileAccess.Write)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, access, FileShare.Read)) { }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return (Marshal.GetHRForException(e) & 0xFFFF) == 32;
        }
        return false;
    }
```